# How do I convert a table from a database into a text file?

Tags: mysql, sql, text-files

I need to take each of the rows in my table and put each row under each other in a text file.

So, I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to "copy" an entire row from a table. Then I could just loop from 0 to however many rows there are in a table, and copy each one, pasting it under the previous one in my text file. Is there any way to do this? I've done a bit of research, but I'm still very inexperienced with Java, and with databases; so I'm finding this a bit tricky.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out : [How to export table data from a mysql database into text file using java?](http://bytes.com/topic/java/answers/599631-how-export-table-data-mysql-database-into-text-file-using-java)

Comment: Thanks to both of you! But I can't seem to get this working! Should this code work even in SQLite? I keep getting an error saying:       "SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "//Users//GeorgeGeorgiades//Documents//School//IT//IT PAT//list.txt" FROM groceries; [ near "INTO": syntax error ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]"             Is there something I'm doing wrong? Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE "/tmp/sql.txt" FROM table WHERE ...;
```

Comment: can't add coments in others answers. it seems there's a problem here `code "//Users//GeorgeGeorgiades//Documents//School//IT//IT PAT//list.txt"